# How to initialize this class of names with a list

Tags: c#, class, object, initialization

What's the best way to initialize this class?

```
public class allNames
{
    public class fullName
    {
        public String firstName { get; set; }
        public String lastName { get; set; }
    }
    public List<fullName> Names { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `new allNames { Names = new List<fullName>() };`

Comment: With values: `new allNames { Names = new List<fullName> { new fullName { firstName = "first", lastName = "last" } } };`

Comment: This question can not be answered. What is best depends on your specific case.

Comment: please update this question with how the class is intended to be used.

Comment: That worked Fabio.  Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With values:

```
new allNames {
    Names = new List<fullName> {
        new fullName { firstName = "first", lastName = "last" }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is this meant as an answer? or is it meant as a comment?